Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. EF Core 8.0 migration
I got this error when Entity Framework Core tools attempt to instantiate my DbContext at design time. Despite having a proper constructor and registering the context correctly in Program.cs, the tools fail to create an instance of the DbContext:

Verified Constructor: Ensured BaseDbContext has a single constructor that takes DbContextOptions, IHttpContextAccessor, and IConfiguration.
Design-Time Factory: Implemented a DesignTimeDbContextFactory to provide EF Core tools with the necessary context configuration.
Service Registration: Confirmed that BaseDbContext and IHttpContextAccessor are correctly registered in Program.cs.
Downgraded Packages: Attempted to downgrade EF Core packages, but the issue persists.

BaseDbContext:
namespace Doing.Retail.Persistence.Contexts
{
    public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
        protected IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public virtual DbSet<OtpAuthenticatorEntity> OtpAuthenticators { get; set; }

        public BaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<BaseDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor
 httpContextAccessor, IConfiguration configuration) 
            : base(options)
        {
            HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
            var currentUserId = claimsPrincipal?.GetUserId();

            var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity<int>>()
                .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.Entity.TimeIns = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        entry.Entity.UserIns = currentUserId.ToString();
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.Entity.TimeUpd = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        entry.Entity.UserUpd = currentUserId.ToString();
                        break;
                }
            }         

            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var seedTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                       .Where(t => typeof(ISeed).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);

            foreach (var type in seedTypes)
            {
                var seedInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as ISeed;
                seedInstance?.Seed(modelBuilder);
            }

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
    }
}

Persistence
public static class PersistenceServiceRegistration
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPersistenceServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var retryPolicy = Policy
                         .Handle<SqlException>()
                         .WaitAndRetry(
                         new[]
                         {
                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                         });

        services.AddDbContext<BaseDbContext>(options =>
                                             options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("localdb"))
                                                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        var repositoryInterfaces = typeof(IUserRepository).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Repository") && x.IsInterface);

        foreach (var interfaceType in repositoryInterfaces)
        {
            var implementationType = typeof(UserRepository).Assembly.GetTypes()
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract && x.Name == interfaceType.Name[1..]);

            if (implementationType != null)
            {
                services.AddScoped(interfaceType, implementationType);
            }
        }

        return services;
    }
}

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
builder.Services.AddSecurityServices();
builder.Services.AddPersistenceServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});

// Build the app
var app = builder.Build();

Connection string:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "localdb": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Retail;Integrated Security=True;"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="8.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is there something I'm missing in my configuration or setup that is preventing the DbContext from being created at design time?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Do you have app.Run() at the end of program.cs?

Yes I have app.Run()

Hi @moongazing, what is your GetUserId method, it seems not the build-in method. Besides, could you pls share what is your Entity<int> and ISeed?  For the exception you get, does it display when you run add-migration? Could you pls share the whole exception?

Hi
GetUserId
public static int GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal) =>
Convert.ToInt32(claimsPrincipal?.Claims(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.FirstOrDefault());
Entity
public class Entity : IEntityTimestamps
{
public string? UserIns { get; set; }
public string? UserUpd { get; set; }
public DateTime? TimeIns { get; set; }
public DateTime? TimeUpd { get; set; }
}
Iseed
public interface ISeed
{
void Seed(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

You're using EF cli or visual studio for creating migration?

I tried two of them

Hi @moongazing, could you pls chec the Console panel in visual studio if there is any exception or error message? When do you get the unable to create a dbxontext, in migration or app runs?
